# JSON inner query in android

Tags: android, json

```
"BRAZIL": {

   "channel": "brazil_ch",        
    "city": {
            "Belo Horizonte": "belohorizonte_ch_org",
            "Brasilia": "brasilia_ch_org",
            "Curitiba": "curitiba_ch_org",
            "Fortaleza": "fortaleza_ch_org",
            "Porto Alegre": "portoalegre_ch_org",
            "Recife": "recife_ch_org",
            "Rio De Janeiro": "rio_ch_org",
            "Salvador, Bahia": "salvador_ch_org",
            "Sao Paulo": "saopaulo_ch_org"
        }

    }
```

This is my JSON. I need to retrieve the channel value in Brazil and also city values. Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Read an article on using [JSON Parsing libraries](http://www.technotalkative.com/lazy-productive-android-developer-3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String channel = jsonObject.getJSONObject("BRAZIL").getString("channel");
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONObject("BRAZIL").getJSONArray("city");
int length = jsonArray.length();
String[] cities = new String[length];
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    String city = jsonArray.getString(i);
    cities[i] = city;
}
```

Comment: can anyone please help me to get this value "belohorizonte_ch_org". Please